# handling html escaping with sqlite's FTS snippet function

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I'm using sqlite's full-text-search support to store documents that may contain `&`, `<` and `>` characters. I intended to use the snippet function to highlight the matches for an html results page, but I don't see an obvious way to escape the text before injecting the markers. I'd rather not escape the text before storing it, because then `amp`, `lt` and `gt` will become tokens.

The simplest workaround I can think of is to escape the pages before storing them, and use a custom tokenizer that would first unescape `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

However... since the default for `snippet(foo)` is to use `<b>` and `</b>`, it really seems like this is a very common use case and I'm convinced that there must be a way to handle this without reinventing the wheel in C. Am I overlooking a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that FTS indeed does not handle markup in text (note how the `<p>` gets chopped up):

```
> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING fts3(content TEXT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES('<p>Isn''t this <font face="Comic Sans">funny</font>?');
> INSERT INTO test VALUES('blah');
> SELECT snippet(test) FROM test WHERE content MATCH 'funny';
p>Isn't this <font face="Comic Sans"><b>funny</b></font>?
> SELECT snippet(test) FROM test WHERE content MATCH 'font';
p>Isn't this <<b>font</b> face="Comic Sans">funny</<b>font</b>>?
```

The cleanest way to store the text is as plain text, unescaped.
However, to get proper highlighting of search results, you have two choices:

- Use the optional parameters of `snippet` to specify markers that are *guaranteed* to never occur in the text (which might not be possible), and convert those to `<b>...` when you are escaping the text for HTML; or
- use the `offsets` function instead and insert the markers by hand.

Comment: Thanks! The text I'm storing is ReStructured Text (and it's all validated already), so I just ended up using markers that get rejected by the docutils rst parser. Not pretty, but it works well.